# TF30073 can't perform undo on an overwrite file merge wsdl

Tags: .net, tfs, merge, wsdl, undo

I have the following problem:

1. Finished some work on the main line ( WebService and an app that consumes it)
2. I wanted to merge my changes on a branch, so I use the merge option.
3. While compiling it turns out that there were diferences on the webservice, so I add the webmethods that are required on the asmx.cs file.
4. I Update the web service reference on the app that consumes it
5. PROBLEM: I can't checkin the wsdl or perform an undo over it. So I'm stuck.
   the message i get is TF30073 SQL Error 515

TF30073: Please contact your administrator. There was an error processing your request
Technical information SQL Error: 515

1. I tried make a baseless branch over only these 2 files with no luck.
2. I try to rename it (which only did things worst) now I also get the error:

TF10210: Source control encountered an error during undo operation:

BTW

1. now i realize that merge is meant to be done only on straightforward changes.
2. i wouldn't like to regenerate the web reference with different names as we are a bunch of developers, but that's my last option for later tonight :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i sorted it out by removing the workspace and adding it again. 
(To avoid losing all the pending changes, perform a shelve)

To achieve this, the following steps were required:

1. File -> source Control -> Workspaces
2. delete current workspace (not just the folder mappings I mean the whole workspace)
3. re-add it again
4. obtain and map everything again.
5. problem is gone

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me. The issue was I had deleted a file (One pending change) and my IDE had generated the same file in the same directory. So, when I was trying to undo the change, it throws the error pop-up window. I deleted the file manually in the directory and I did undo the change. Everything went well.